# Anycasted Service responding from regular IP address

Tags: routing, bgp, anycast

Trying to set up an anycast DNS setup. For the time being, we have two routers, R01 and our Mgmt router that we're using until we move to SDN (in testing phases).

The problem we're having is the DNS receives the query on 10.1.2.8 like it should but it responds via 10.99.0.130 using NAT. The box that the DNS server is on has a gateway of last resort set to .1 for upgrades and other traffic, and 10.1.2.8 is configured on the loopback interface. How do we force responses back through the way it came (through R01)?

```
             Internet
BGP AS 64000   +   +      Static Routed
Aggregating +--+   +----+ 10.99.0.128/29
10.1.2.0/24 |           | SNAT on .130
   +--------+-+    +----+------------+
   |R01       |    |Mgmt/OOB Rtr     |
   |          |    |                 |
   +-----+----+    +---------+-------+
      .2 |                   | .1
         |  172.19.0.0/24    |
    +----+----+--------------+---+
              |
              | .4
      +---------------+
      |DNS Service    |
      |Anycast        |
      |VIP 10.1.2.8/32|
      +---------------+
```

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DNS server doesn't know where the packet(s) came from. Thus responses will follow whatever the route table says is the best path to the destination -- which is a different path if the origin was R01.

You'll need some sort of *policy-based routing* on the server -- route based on src, not dest; anything *from* 10.1.2.8 should be forwarded to 172.19.0.2. How to set that up on your (unspecified) host OS is off-topic here. (as it isn't a router)